# MySQL does not read user specific options in ~/.my.cnf

Tags: mysql, configuration, character-set

I want the server to run an initial SQL query every time it starts:

```
[mysqld]
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
```

and I want it to be only user specific not globally. so I created a .my.cnf in my user's home directory(`~/.my.cnf`) but when I try to see if it has affected the server it does not show my added setting and it seems that my settings are being ignored by the server:

```
    mysqld --print-defaults
------------------------------------
--user=mysql 
--pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid 
--socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock 
--port=3306 
--basedir=/usr 
--datadir=/var/lib/mysql 
--tmpdir=/tmp 
--lc-messages-dir=/usr/share/mysql 
--skip-external-locking 
--bind-address=0.0.0.0 --

key_buffer_size=16M 
--max_allowed_packet=16M 
--thread_stack=192K 
--thread_cache_size=8 
--myisam-recover-options=BACKUP 
--query_cache_limit=1M 
--query_cache_size=16M 
--log_error=/var/log/mysql/error.log 
--expire_logs_days=10 
--max_binlog_s

ize=100M 
--default_password_lifetime=0
```

also this is the result of  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_%';` :

[image]

I want theses params to be set to `'utf8mb4'` wach time the server boots.

```
character_set_client
character_set_results
character_set_connection
```

also I should say that I use **Laravel Vagrant** as my development environment

Answer (score 2):

`init-connect` is ignored when you connect as the MySQL `root` user.

Check the file `config/database.php` for Laravel.  It needs to say something like: `'mysql' => [..., 'charset' => 'utf8mb4', 'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci', ...]`

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: what should I do sir . I want to store emojis in mysql . but my db shows ??? instead of emojis

Comment: Also I tried with a non-root account but the same happened

Comment: Actually, it is any MySQL user with `SUPER` priv.

Comment: @Ramin - I added Laravel setup info.  Perhaps it is overriding `init_connect`.  (Grrrr)

Comment: @RickJames I did that also sir but its strange why it does not work I should probably go after other solutions :)

Comment: @Ramin - If you find a solution, please report it here; sounds like I need to learn something.

Answer (score 0):

With the mysql client, to use a character set different from the default, you could explicitly execute `SET NAMES` every time you start up.

To accomplish the same result more easily, add the `--default-character-set` option setting to your mysql command line or in your option file. For example, the following option file setting changes the three connection-related character set variables set to `koi8r` each time you invoke mysql:

```
[mysql]
default-character-set=koi8r
```

If you are using the mysql client with auto-reconnect enabled (which is not recommended), it is preferable to use the charset command rather than `SET NAMES`. For example:

```
mysql> charset utf8

Charset changed
```

The charset command issues a `SET NAMES` statement, and also changes the default character set that mysql uses when it reconnects after the connection has dropped.

Comment: For More detail Please visit at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8

Comment: I want to know why mysql ignores my conf file

Comment: You haven't write correct key word that's why mysql ignores it

Comment: its a server param not a client thats why I used mysqld

Comment: you should write in [mysqld] as below mentioned and then check by the query:- show variables like "%character%";

[mysqld] 
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci' 
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4' 
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci 
skip-character-set-client-handshake
Result is